# ruby faye-websocket openshift

Tags: ruby, websocket

I am having a problem running a ruby websocket example on openshift. I can't find any quickstart. I already tried this.

***[mifo.sk/post/ruby-websockets-on-openshift/](http://mifo.sk/post/ruby-websockets-on-openshift/)***

I am always having this error:

**Sorry, but I am websocket app.**

Here is my app.
http://ruby-reedleoneil.rhcloud.com/

Comment: have you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`? Or checked the logs? `heroku logs --tail`.

Comment: my paas provider is redhat openshift

Comment: Are you using a framework (if so, did you perform `db` migrations and deployment tasks)...? If not, is your Faye Websocket example using the correct `WEBSOCKET_PORT` assigned by the openshift? Is your client connecting to the `WEBSOCKET_PORT` as indicated by the [blog post](http://mifo.sk/post/ruby-websockets-on-openshift/)?

Comment: I am not using a frame work. I created a ruby application **`rhc app create ruby ruby-2.0`**, then copied this [https://github.com/mfojtik/openshift-ruby-websockets-demo](https://github.com/mfojtik/openshift-ruby-websockets-demo) to my app directory. Run these commands **`git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push`**

Here is my app [https://ruby-reedleoneil.rhcloud.com/app](https://ruby-reedleoneil.rhcloud.com/app). But when i access it with port 8000 it does not work [https://ruby-reedleoneil.rhcloud.com:8000/app](https://ruby-reedleoneil.rhcloud.com:8000/app)

Comment: i can run [these](https://www.igvita.com/2009/12/22/ruby-websockets-tcp-for-the-browser/) examples locally but no luck in trying to deploy them in openshift, i already used ENV['OPENSHIFT_MY_IP'] and ENV['OPENSHIFT_MY_PORT']

Comment: i manually installed the gems, manually run the action hooks, still no luck :(

Comment: The application works fine for me... I tested access using javascript on the browser: `ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.hostname + ':8000/'); ws.onclose = (e) => console.log(e); ws.onmessage = (e) => console.log(e);` ... I got a message with the time every second.

Comment: thank you for your response, i tried it at home and it works... i guess our company is blocking port 8000 or websockets...